# Grid Layout elements issue

Tags: android, grid-layout

I have an issue with gidLayout. I have a this grid:

[image]

this is how it looks in android studio. But when I installing the app in a tablet, all elements look bad.

All the element, are placed correctly in his row and column, but 
their background do not touch. Like the layout_columnWeight and layout_rowWeight doesn't works..
See the 200ºC text element:

[image]

The code of grid layout and all elements in xml:

```
    <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:columnCount="12"
            android:rowCount="12"
            android:background="@color/black"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Barra notificacions"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:background="@color/fondoGrid"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"

                android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:layout_columnSpan="7" />
 ...other textViews
```

Comment: Have you tried `<TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"`

Comment: Yes, but in this case, all the element have a with of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `layout_width=wrap_content` on the grid layout. This should fix the issue. 
I had a similar issue; however, my gridlayout was contained inside a frame layout and so I had to set the width to wrap_content on both.